# Do I have to add a handler to each form element, to stop keyup event from bubbling up to a parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault, custom-element, event-bubbling

How to avoid to add a handler to each form element manually, but instead to set some default once in the code, so that one group of form elements (currently marked in the example by `class="preventbubbling"`, but other mechanisms are welcome also, like `custom elements`) by default prevent bubbling?

```
<script>function react(ev,el) {console.log(ev);} </script>
<div name="dialog" onkeyup="react(event,this);">
  <textarea class="allowbubbling"></textarea> 
  <textarea class="preventbubbling"></textarea>
  and many other form elements inputs etc
</div>
```

Typing in the textarea also triggers the div's onkeyup.

Is there a simple way to let some form element allow bubbling, and some to prevent bubbling by sort of default?

P.S. Beside the simple approach, does creating custom elements work properly enough well on current major browsers?

Comment: I added in the question body the detail from the title. I'm looking for a way not to have to add the propagation stop manually to each element.

Answer (score 0):

[`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is what you'll need.

If you do not want the `textarea` `keyup` event to bubble to the `div`, you would need something like this:

```html
<script>function react(ev,el) {console.log(ev);} </script>

<div name="dialog" onkeyup="react(event,this);">
  <textarea class="allowbubbling"></textarea> 
  <textarea class="preventbubbling" onkeyup="event.stopPropagation()"></textarea>
  and many other form elements inputs etc
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have.

You can stop propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the inner element's event.